# Looping issue to populate spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have hundreds of photos I would like to embed in Excel with their filenames.  I would like to populate the spreadsheet: Down 10 rows `A1-A10` and then to the right from `A1-BT10`.

The VBA I have this far does the following:

1. VBA asks for folder containing photos
2. Sets column width and row height to accept filenames/images
3. Sets column width `A:BT` to whole filenames and images
4. Embeds file name in `A:1` and resized image in `B:1`
5. Repeats embedding until all filenames and images are embedded, e.g., but only in ColumnsA/B.

I need embedded objects to be across the spreadsheet instead of just down, i.e., down 10 rows – up and right – down 10 rows – up and right, etc.

It is best to have a folder with a couple hundred JPEGS and then run the code. Attachment shows intended layout.

Shows populated sheet the way wanted

[image]

Tried loops at various points but failed.

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmbedImages()
    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim Flder As FileDialog
    Dim Folderpath, fStr, myPath, Filename, getFolder As String
    Dim fso, NoOfFiles, listfiles, fls, strCompFilePath
    Dim counter
    ' Get source images folder
    Set Flder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Flder
        .Title = "Select the folder containing data"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    getFolder = Folderpath
    Set Flder = Nothing
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.getFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.getFolder(Folderpath).Files
    For Each fls In listfiles
        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            ' // include image extensions here \\
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
                Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
                Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Filename = fls.Name
                If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
                    Filename = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
                End If
                ' Set alignment as AlignCenter
                ActiveSheet.Columns("A:BT").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                ' Sets WrapText
                ActiveSheet.Range("A:BT").Select
                With Selection
                    .WrapText = True
                End With
                ' Insert Filename
                ActiveSheet.Range("A" & counter).Value = Filename
                ' Set ColumnWidth for 29 FileNames/Images
                ActiveSheet.Range("A:B,D:G,I:L,N:Q,S:V,X:AA,AC:AF,AH:AK,AM:AP,AR:AU,AW:AZ,BB:BE,BG:BJ,BL:BO,BQ:BT").ColumnWidth = 19
                ' Sets RowHeight for scaled image
                ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).RowHeight = 70
                ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, counter)
                ActiveSheet.Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, counter)
    'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        '// change image sizes here \\
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & counter).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Please *indent* your code when posting.

Comment: Apologies.  Indented 4 characters as prompted before posting but it didn't get in correctly.

Comment: Adding ... If I have 300 rows, I want colsA&B/rows 11 to end moved up and to right, then repeated until long initial A&B is spread out in 10-row columns.

Answer (score 1):

You were hard coding "A" and "B" columns where column numbers would be better suited for looping every 10 rows and advancing the column. I moved some of the formatting from inside the For loop to above it and now reference the columns numerically. You also need to account for 1 set in AB, skip C, a set in DE and FG and skip H, rinse and repeat. I tested the below modification of your code on a set of 82 jpgs and it seems to produce a layout as in your diagram. The function now accepts a third argument as well.

```
Option Explicit

Sub EmbedImages()

    Dim mainWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim Flder As FileDialog
    Dim Folderpath, fStr, myPath, Filename, getFolder As String
    Dim fso, NoOfFiles, listfiles, fls, strCompFilePath
    Dim curRow As Long
    Dim curCol As Long
    Dim trips as Long

    curRow = 0
    curCol = 1
    trips = 1
    ' Get source images folder
    Set Flder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With Flder
        .Title = "Select the folder containing data"
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        Folderpath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    getFolder = Folderpath
    Set Flder = Nothing
    Set mainWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.getFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.getFolder(Folderpath).Files

    ' Set alignment as AlignCenter - moved this out of the loop
            ' Set ColumnWidth for 29 FileNames/Images

        ActiveSheet.Range("A:B,D:G,I:L,N:Q,S:V,X:AA,AC:AF,AH:AK,AM:_
        AP,AR:AU,AW:AZ,BB:BE,BG:BJ,BL:BO,BQ:BT").ColumnWidth = 19
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A:BT").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
    ' Sets WrapText
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:BT").Select
    With Selection
        .WrapText = True
    End With

    For Each fls In listfiles
        strCompFilePath = Folderpath & "\" & Trim(fls.Name)
        If strCompFilePath <> "" Then
            ' // include image extensions here \\
            If (InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
                Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "jpeg", vbTextCompare) > 1 _
                Or InStr(1, strCompFilePath, "png", vbTextCompare) > 1) Then
                curRow = curRow + 1
                If curRow = 11 Then
                    curRow = 1
                    trips = trips + 1
                    If trips Mod (2) = 0 Then
                        curCol = curCol + 3
                    Else
                        curCol = curCol + 2
                    End If
                End If
                Filename = fls.Name
                If InStr(Filename, ".") > 0 Then
                    Filename = Left(Filename, InStr(Filename, ".") - 1)
                End If
                ' Insert Filename
                ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow, curCol).Value = Filename
                ' Sets RowHeight for scaled image
                ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow, curCol + 1).RowHeight = 70
                ActiveSheet.Cells(curRow, curCol + 1).Activate
                Call insert(strCompFilePath, curRow, curCol + 1)
                ActiveSheet.Activate
            End If
        End If
    Next
    'mainWorkBook.Save
End Sub

Function insert(PicPath, thisRow, thisCol)
    'MsgBox PicPath
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.insert(PicPath)
        '// change image sizes here \\
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 50
            .Height = 70
        End With
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(thisRow, thisCol).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(thisRow, thisCol).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Roy ... thank you.  I am a begining novice so I try to look for code, compare differences and then modify and try.  I routinely get hundreds of pick (lawyer) and the ultimate goal is to construct as the diagram as 10-deep rows from A:BT with will accept 290 filenames/pictures and then have it repeat back at A:11/B:11.  The result would be 290 per row.  Thank you again.  My work is now cut out and I hope I can interpret and then apply.

Comment: You're welcome @LawGuy. I have repurposed many a piece of exiting code. This could be easily modified to queue up another set of rows after each group of 290 pics is completed. Also since you are a novice, fyi when you declare x, y, z as string, only z is a string and x & y are variants. To get the intended behavior, you explicitly define the type for each var; x as string, y as string, z as string. You would also add types to the function parameters.

Comment: I'll gladly take any tips, so thank you for getting me going.